# dism mount-wim in docker

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

When I try to use `dism /Mount-WIM` in `microsoft/windowsservercore` image I'm getting next error:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Error: 0xc1420121

The image could not be mounted because the wimmount.sys driver is not installed on this machine.  To fix this error, install the wimmount.sys driver.
```

Is it possible to use `dism /Mount-WIM` in docker?